# Jenkins build history ALWAYS disappearing

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am being plagued with a terrible problem. I am consistently losing jenkins build history for my multibranch pipelines. The problem is really bad because the patch version for our software is based on the build counter. If this get's reset it messes up our deployment documentation in a very bad way. this is not happening with all of my pipelines, but it does happen on my pipelines that have lot's of builds (100s per day). The weird thing is that while we build this project 100s of times per day, the branch that get's consistently reset is our master branch and that is very frustrating.  Has anyone had this problem before? This has been happening for months.

Jenkins ver. 2.199
Branch filtering happens in the Jenkinsfile

If you need more info I can provide it.

Comment: does jenkinsfile configured with `buildDiscarder` properties in it? If so what is configured?

Comment: We do not use the buildDiscarder plugin.

Comment: how do you mention the number of builds to be stored for a specific branch?

Comment: That setting is not configured. If it is not configured is there a default?

Comment: I think I found the problem. the branch selection for my SCM was set to exclude branches also filed as PRs. there is a chance that if a PR is open for so long, the branch will be removed from Jenkins and thus build history disappears. I'll post an answer if this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch selection for my SCM was set to exclude branches also filed as PRs. This causes your multi branch pipeline to re-scan and remove branches from build history it cannot see. To fix this set your branch discovery to 'All Branches'